# Auto or manual refreshing of mounted volumes

Tags: mount, nfs, refresh

I use Transmit to mount a Linux server disk on my Mac.

[image]

The issue is that when I do something on the remote server with ssh, the change is not reflected in the mounted volume in my mac.

How can I manually/automatically update the changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refresh using the refresh command in the Transmit Disk menu bar item.

> ### Transmit 4.1.1
>
> #### Released on 9/14/10
>
> - Transmit Disk has been improved dramatically!
>
>   - …
>   - Added a new 'Finder Refresh' command Transmit Disk menu to reload Finder file listings

Comment: I works for Finder, but not for PathFinder. I guess there should be some command for it.